# Add .pm file to CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a .pm file with a 30+ subs. The functionality in those subs needs to be called from my CakePHP pages. What is the Cake way to include the .pm file in a CakePHP project so I can call the subs from a View or Controller?

Where should I put the .pm file? How should I include the file into the CakePHP project? How do I call the subs in the .pm file?

I can't find anything in the CakePHP documentation. The place that it seems it should be is in the App, but I can't find anything to do what I want to do.

Comment: `.pm` files generally contain Perl code. What makes you think CakePHP can use them?

Comment: Yes, .pm files do generally contain Perl code. How can I call them from CakePHP?

Comment: CakePHP has no way to call Perl code. It's... PHP. If you have perl *scripts* (not just some functions), you may be able to call them as subprocesses and get their output in PHP code.

Comment: I can rename the .pm files to .pl files, and then call them from PHP using "passthru()". This doesn't seem very "Cake-y" though, and I hoped there was a Cake way to do this.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339786/cakephp-use-perl-php-files

Comment: Sort of. I'm trying different approaches to solve the problem, and have different questions.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to use Perl code within a **PHP** framework?

Comment: Because I have a huge library of inherited Perl scripts that need to be run from the website interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP is a PHP framework. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module), a `.pm` file contains Perl source code basically composed of function definitions. From the PHP point of view, that's as reusable as the blueprints of a Toyota. I suppose it's technically possible to write a PHP extension that's able to compile the Perl code and expose its methods to PHP functions but it'd be a daunting task.

The obvious workaround is to write a Perl executable that loads the module, does whatever you need and prints the output in a format that PHP can use. Afterwards, [program execution functions](https://www.php.net/exec) are your friends.

Comment: Yes, I can just use PHP stuff, but I was hoping there was an official CakePHP way of doing this. It sounds like there must not be.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your perl scripts work(I have no idea what the difference between .pm and .pl is ),  you could create a model or component and access the data using PHP's exec function like so:

```
exec("path_to_perl /path/to/script.pl arguments to be passed",$output);
```

Wrap the perl output in your model/components methods. Than in your controller just call the model/component method passing in the relevant arguments.

NOTE: just make sure when running this command you have properly secured the input/output data from the scripts